# Filtering within REST api

Tags: php, api, rest

We're currently in the process of building a RESTful API. Now, it's a matter of what the best way of tackling filtering is.

We have `/products`. `/products` returns all given products you have access to. Now, let's say you want the products where the `description` matches exactly 'No description'. You'd get `/products?description=No+description`.

Now, ideally we would have more filter options. Show only products where the stock is more than or equal to 1, but less than 10. Show only products where the name ends in `black`, or starts with `white`. What is the best practice of doing this? Would we use logical operators in the URL, how would we escape wild cards?

Current state of affairs is:

`/products?product_name=%25black` will find all products with names ending in black.

or

`/products?product_name=white%25` will find all products with names starting with white.

%25 is the encoded form of `%`. So far so good.

But what if someone wants to find a product where the name matches the literal `%` character? Or wants to find products with stock? Would it be best to introduce

`min_stock` and `max_stock`, or is it possible (or do we even want to?) to use logical operators (`?stock=>=1&stock=<=5`). Is there a standard for handling URLs or situations like this?

Are we overthinking? Is it possible? Should we not do filtering our end, but let users figure it out themselves?

Comment: See also http://soabits.blogspot.dk/2013/10/url-structures-and-hyper-media-for-web.html in the "Filtering" section for some ideas. Maybe even take a look at OData URL structures: http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/url-conventions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST paradigm is about ressources (all you access is ressource) and human understandability. That's why you make your listing url plural.

With that said, I **do** think, if you want to filter in two different ways (with `=`, `like`, regex...) you have two possibilitiees :

- first create three different filters `product_name_exact`, `product_name_like`, `product_name_regex`. It looks like python.django way of filtering and it's quite elegant;
- second way : create one `query` field, and then a `query_mode` it is quite the way bing api works.

Comment: OK, I do like the idea of having _exact and _like, but how would it work? If I want to find product with names starting with white, or ending in black? `product_name_like=black`?

Comment: you can use _end, _start, _contain instead of _like but you can also try to use the urlencoded char for `\\`  before any `%`.